# watch file to see whos accessing/writing it and log it

Tags: security, debian, files, malware

I am facing some malware problems on my webserver.

I updated third party software such as Wordpress to the latest version, disabled root logins and my users password complex enough but still someone or something is changing my `index.php` files, adding some code that causes malware alerts on many visitor's browsers.

Now as I'm not able to find out who or what is doing that, I think about watching one of the `index.php` files which are changed periodically so I can see who is accessing it.

I would like to know what program and user is accessing it. Is there any possibility to do so? I checked `inotify-tools`, but it seems it simply tells me about changes, but not who is changing it, am I right?

Comment: Since your box has been compromised, there's plenty of suggested reading here: http://serverfault.com/q/218005/26130 http://serverfault.com/q/218138/26130 http://security.stackexchange.com/q/9234/1472

Answer (score 2):

I have had a pretty good experience with the package `auditd` (found in apt). It is a comprehensive audit logging daemon. The only possible problem here is you definitely need root access to install it.

Some basic instructions can be found at
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html

Comment: @NovumCoder This is worth a read too: http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/01/a-brief-introduction-to-auditd/

Answer (score 0):

> but not who is changing it, am I right?

Not really.

Most likely the site is being exploited remotely via the php scripts running on it (AFAIK the *current* version of Wordpress is reasonably secure but there are a lot of third-party plugins riddled with vulnerabilitites). If this is the case then all you'll see is the uid which your PHP runs as - you'll then need to reconcile this with your webserver logs to see where the attack might have come from. But does that help you solve the problem? I think not. (also checking against the wtmp log).

A partial solution might be to ensure that the *all* the files are not writeable by the PHP uid. Which provide some protection - but you'll lose any visibility you have of how the files are being modified.

If it were me, I'd go with inotify/log reconcilliation approach - but I'd want to find the vulnerability and eliminate it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a windows box you can enable auditing on that directory.

IIS:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2010/03/19/iis-7-5-how-to-enable-iis-configuration-auditing.aspx

Server 2008 & GPO:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverfiles/thread/da689e43-d51d-4005-bc48-26d3c387e859/